# Install "ia32-libs" package on Windows to use in Linux

Tags: package-management, gcc, arm, toolchain

I have recently installed a GCC ARM Embedded toolchain for Linux (to run on a 64-bit machine). However, the  pre-built version of Linaro GCC runs on 32 bit machines. The solution is simple: `apt-get install ia32-libs` to install the ia32-libs package. The problem is that the Linux machine which I am working with has no internet connection. Therefore, I cannot do installations through that manner. I am using a Windows machine for internet access (which is how I am able to ask this question). My question is then: is it possible to download the package on a Windows machine, put it on a USB and install it on the Linux machine? If so, where I can download the package manually from (instead of typing `apt-get install ia32-libs`?

Comment: What is your distro?

Comment: I'm sorry but what do you mean by "distro"?

Comment: He's asking for your »flavor« of Linux.  Debian, Ubuntu, Mint, …?

Comment: Oh. It's Ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is download Ubuntu .iso on your computer, then use SFTP (FTP via SSH) to upload .iso file to your server.

On your server you can mount the .iso file like this:

```
mkdir /mnt/ubuntu_iso
mount -o loop /path/to/file.iso /mnt/ubuntu_iso
```

Now edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and comment out everything that is not cd-rom related.

Then run `apt-cdrom` to add cdrom to repository:

```
apt-cdrom -d "/mnt/ubuntu_iso" -r
```

After this run `apt-get update` an you should be able to install packages from erpositories in livecd.